# Kentico Required document no longer exists

Tags: kentico

I have a Kentico 5.5 site and some custom document types. When trying to edit the HomePage in CMSDesk it says  **Required document no longer exists, please select another document.**

I have not deleted the HomePage but the document type was missing. So I restored the document type by exporting and importing from another of my sites. The error is still present.

When I create a new Homepage with the same document type it shows the *this site has no content please go to cmsdesk*

Is there something wrong with my document type or is my DB just ruined?

UPDATE: I imported a new document type from my other site along with a page template and a role. After which the error occurs. I think it blows away the Homepage's document type or some other related file.

Comment: What is the document type that you're importing?  Check the code name.  Maybe it is overwriting the home page document type.

Comment: Yes it was doing this but the code name was different. What was happening was the ids were the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had imported a document type and it was from another server where the id's were not in sync so the new document type overwrote the old document type with the same id. Ids are sequential so if you are importing from one site into another be very careful to always have all the same document types and have them all created in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

That happened on a staging site once. We tried a number of things in kentico and directly manipulating records in the database but could not get it to sorted. In the end we exported the objects from the old site, installed a site and imported the objects from the old site and we were back up and running in 20 mins. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding a new home page, and changing your site settings to use that as the default home page.

Comment: Yes I have tried that and then the new homepage gets the error :S